# Close socket from DialogFragment

Tags: android, sockets

I have an `Activity` that's running a thread that's got a `DatagramSocket` listening to a port for packets. Basically when a dialog pops up, if the user presses an 'Accept' button, I would like to close the `Socket`, and start a different `Activity`. How do I close the `Socket` from a `DialogFragment`?

```
public class OnlineUsers extends Activity {
    //some code
    MsgFwd mservice;
    private final Handler mhandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case REQUEST_CHAT:
                    String sourceIP = (String) msg.obj;
                    //SHOW DIALOG
                    MyAlert myAlert = new MyAlert();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_MYIP, myIP);
                    myAlert.setArguments(args);
                    myAlert.show(getFragmentManager(), "My Alert");
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mservice = new MsgFwd(this, mhandler);
            mservice.start();
        }
    }

    public class MsgFwd {

        Context fContext;
        private final Handler fHandler;
        fthread fconthread;

        public MsgFwd(Context context, Handler handler) {
            fContext = context;
            fHandler = handler;
        }

        public synchronized void start() {
            fconthread = new fthread();
            fconthread.start();
        }

        public synchronized void stop() {
           if (fconthread!=null){fconthread.cancel();fconthread = null;}
        }

        private class fthread extends Thread {
            //...
            DatagramSocket sock;

            public fthread() {
                sock = new DatagramSocket(someport);
            }

            void run() {
                while (true) {
                    sock.receive(packet);
                }
            }

            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    sock.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyAlert extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Chat Notification");
            builder.setMessage(chatid + " wants to chat with you");
            builder.setNegativeButton("Reject", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Negative button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Positive button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), newMessageFwd.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            Dialog dialog = builder.create();

            return dialog;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I could just say "By calling `close()` on the socket." but then again if it were that simple you wouldn't be asking here. So could you please give us more information? Maybe show us what you have tried so far or post some relevant code.

Comment: pls check my edit, when user presses Accept on dialog I want to start a new activity but I dont know how to close the socket that was started.

Comment: You didn't post all of your code, did you? Because what you posted mostly seems disconnected. It's difficult to give you an accurate answer like that but I will give it a try anyway. Give me a few minutes to type up an answer.

Comment: yea my apologies its difficult to format code on stack overflow and I've got a lot of code.

Comment: It's actually not that difficult. Format it in your IDE and just copy and paste it, the formatting will be preserved. Correcting the indentions of your code took me like 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is add a listener to your `DialogFragment` and which gets called when the user clicks accept and then tell the thread that the `Socket` is supposed to be closed. So  to do that we will modify your MyAlert `Fragment`. On a side note: Normally you would nest the listener definition inside the `Fragment` but since you haven't posted your full code I can't be sure that this would work in your case, for example MyAlert would have to be static to allow further nesting and that could break your code if you use member variables of your `Activity` in your `DialogFragment`. So you are going to have to decide where you put the listener interface, if possible nest it in your `Fragment`. Anyway here is the listener interface:

```
public interface MyAlertAcceptListener {
    public void onAccept();
}
```

Now we add the listener implementation to your `Fragment`, as I already noted you should also nest the listener interface in there if possible:

```
public class MyAlert extends DialogFragment {

    private MyAlertAcceptListener alertListener;

    public MyAlertAcceptListener getAlertListener() {
        return alertListener;
    }

    public void setAlertListener(MyAlertAcceptListener listener) {
        this.alertListener = listener;
    }

    protected void notifyAcceptListener() {
        if(this.alertListener != null) {
            this.alertListener.onAccept();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Chat Notification");
        builder.setMessage(chatid + " wants to chat with you");
        builder.setNegativeButton("Reject", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Negative button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Positive button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Notify the listener when the user presses accept
                notifyAcceptListener(); 
            }
        });
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Now when you open your `DialogFragment` in your handler you just have to set the listener like this:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
        case REQUEST_CHAT:
            String sourceIP = (String) msg.obj;
            //SHOW DIALOG
            MyAlert myAlert = new MyAlert();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_MYIP, myIP);
            myAlert.setArguments(args);

            myAlert.setAlertListener(new MyAlertAcceptListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAccept() {
                    // In your Listener call stop() on mservice to close the socket
                    mservice.stop();
                }
            });

            myAlert.show(getFragmentManager(), "My Alert");
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want you can also define your listener like you did with your handler:

```
private final MyAlertAcceptListener acceptListener = new MyAlertAcceptListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccept() {
        mservice.stop();
    }
};
```

And then you just have to set it like this:

```
myAlert.setAlertListener(acceptListener);
```

If you have any further question please feel free to ask!

**EDIT:** I have modified my example code to fit your project

Comment: thanks for the reply! can i ask some more questions about this project im currently doing.

Comment: Sure. Edit them in your question and comment here to notify me. Or if it is bigger problem consider asking an new question.

Comment: Is it possible to email you instead

Comment: I think you're better of posting another question here. If you post it within the next one or two hours I might just see it too.